# AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has not been refreshed yet using ApplicationContextAware

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring beans in a non-spring framework and for that I have implemented the *ApplicationContextAware* to access the spring beans.

```
@Service
public class ApplicationContextProviderService implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ApplicationContextProviderService.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanType) {
        System.out.println("bean out: " + applicationContext);
        return applicationContext.getBean(beanType);
    }

}
```

I try to access a Spring service: ConnectionStateService from the non-spring class:

```
this.connectionStateService = ApplicationContextProviderService.getBean(ConnectionStateService.class);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:
**org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7f485fda has not been refreshed yet     at
** org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1072) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1102) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]   at com.example.app.service.ApplicationContextProviderService.getBean(ApplicationContextProviderService.java:19) ~[classes/:na]  at com.example.app.CustomFilter.<init>(CustomFilter.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related when the application tries to call  to ApplicationContext before the application runs, so you won't be able to have application context because it wasn't created. The solution is create a singleton for ConnectionStateService class so you won't need to create a service for calling the ApplicationContext.

```
public class ConnectionStateService { 

// static variable instance of type Singleton 
private static ConnectionStateService single_instance = null; 

// private constructor restricted to this class itself 
private ConnectionStateService() { 
 // some stuffs for initialize here
}  

// static method to create instance of Singleton class 
public static ConnectionStateService getInstance()  { 
if (instance == null) 
     instance = new ConnectionStateService(); 
     return instance; 
}
```

}

Comment: Service annotation is inhereited from @Component

Comment: You said it’s better to use to inject it before so what it should change ?

Comment: Yes I guess, I did a test before and I noticed that it is first Component injected that is referenced like Bean  I think that your issue is in method you are calling the context. Could you please add that method?

Comment: Mykhailo has started a chat and I have posted several details there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184244/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-conquester 

My first post gives the main details.

Comment: Update: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184244/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-conquester

Comment: This issue was primarily because of application context not being initialized. Although the cause is unknown to me but that was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting the bean when the context is not initialized

So actually be sure you are invoking this piece of code :

```
this.connectionStateService = ApplicationContextProviderService.getBean(ConnectionStateService.class);
```

after context is initialized

Comment: ApplicationContext object has no refresh method. The bean does get returned when called from a spring context but it doesn't work when called from a non-spring class.

Comment: AnnotationConfigApplicationContext has it

Comment: And you are having an exception. My purposes are that context is not initialized yet

Comment: When I do that, I get the error that the context can be refreshed only once.

Comment: When you are calling your method from non bean class ?

Comment: The spring main app initializes the non-spring framework. The framework listens for http-requests and when an incoming connection comes, it tries to access the spring based beans for backend processing.

Comment: Are you sure your application context is started ?

Comment: I put a print statement in setApplicationContext and also in the getBean method above. They print the applicationContext object so it is set.

Comment: As I see you are using this piece of code inside filter ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184244/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-conquester).

Comment: Filters are initialized before context start up actually when you try to call init method in filter with invoking those code which get bean from application context .It means that applicationcontext could not registered those bean , it seems to be that

Comment: I have given a detailed reply on the chat.

Comment: Update: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184244/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-conquester